# How can I update the table based on a SELECT query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

```
 SELECT SignIn.[VisitorFirstName], SignIn.[VisitorLastName], SignIn.[SignInDateTime]
FROM SignIn
WHERE SignIn.SignInDateTime Is Null;
```

This provides me with a list of records that have no SignIn time. I want to update them automatically to make the date/time a week from today

How can I do this? I am using MS-ACCESS 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `update`:

```
update SignIn
    set SignInDateTime = dateadd('d', 1, DATE())
    where SignInDateTime is null;
```